# Windows 10 上の IIS に Windows 認証を追加するには？

Tags: windows-10, iis

Windows認証で作成したASP WEBフォームを公開するにあたり、IISにWindows認証を追加したいと思っています。
しかし、検索してみるとWindows Serverの「役割と機能の追加」から設定しているようです。

私の環境は Windows 10 Pro なのですが、IISだけでは設定できないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境:**
Windows 10 Pro バージョン 21H1 (OSビルド 19043,1288)

Comment: 私自身は IIS に詳しくないので直接の回答はできませんが、質問のタイトルは具体的なものにした方が回答もつきやすくなると思います。今回は一例として編集してみましたが、次回以降の参考にしてください。

Comment: 検索するととりあえずこんな記事が見つかりますので参考になるかも。[WINDOWS10にてIIS(WEBサーバー)をインストール・構成する方法](http://www.floatgarden.net/server/windows10_iis_server.html), [WordPressをIISでWindows 10に構築](https://www.pc-koubou.jp/magazine/12120), [Windows 認証の概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-authentication-overview), [ASP.NET Core で Windows 認証を構成する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth), [IIS を使用した Windows での ASP.NET Core のホスト](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iis-configuration)

Comment: 公開ってのがどういう使い方なのかわかりませんが Windows 10 Pro をサーバー用途につかうのは EULA 違反かもしれません（だから Windows Server でしか記事がない）

Comment: ライセンスに従った内容とユーザー数範囲内のサービスならば出来そうですが。[一般向けWindowsは一部特例においてのみ、サーバー機能の提供が許可されています！](https://www.haruru29.net/blog/windows-share-files-20-devices/#Windows-3), [Windows ライセンスについて](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/21896335-7f5d-4697-b690-fddc90064ee0/), [Does a Window 10 license allow using it as a Web server?](https://superuser.com/q/1496496) 思い込みや期待による解釈ではなくしかるべきところに確認した方が良いでしょうね。

Comment: みなさまコメントありがとうございます。なるほど、ライセンスに絡むところだったんですね。今回作成したASPアプリは30人程度の会社の中での情報共有を目的としています。担当部署にライセンス条項を確認し、進めていこうと思います。大変助かりました、ありがとうございます。